# Nexus 7 (2013) 32GB Wifi only - difference between 1C010A and 1A034A?

Tags: nexus-7

I’m seeing these two codes appear in the product descriptions on various sites in my country (Croatia). What do these codes mean, why is the same product available via two separate codes and which one should I buy?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A store clerk informed me that those codes represent different suppliers and the the actual devices are identical.